# RxJava scheduler always works in the same thread with sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have tried to run each computation on different thread, but whatever Scheduler i used it running always on single thread.

```
PublishProcessor processor = PublishProcessor.create();

    processor
        .doOnNext(i ->System.out.println(i.toString()+" emitted on "+Thread.currentThread().getId()))
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(i -> {
            System.out.println(i.toString()+" received on "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
        });
    processor.onNext(2);
    processor.onNext(3);
    processor.onNext(4);
    processor.onNext(5);
    processor.onNext(6);


    while (true) {}
```

The output would be:

```
2 emitted on 1
3 emitted on 1
4 emitted on 1
5 emitted on 1
6 emitted on 1
2 received on 13
3 received on 13
4 received on 13
5 received on 13
6 received on 13
```

Thread 13 processes the next value only after sleeping, but i want to have few separate sleeping threads in that case.
Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong, please?

Comment: observeOn only effect down stream which is your subscriber. you need subscribeOn to effect where the processor working. 
if you need something parallex, whether you use build-in parallel operator or something like flatMap(o -> o.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())). More info you can see here : http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.fr/2015/11/rxjava-achieving-parallelization.html

Comment: Thank you very much, that link was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

`.observeOn(...)` makes effect by changing to the item flow to another thread but it's always the same thread.

If you want to create a new thread for every item you can do

```
processor
    .doOnNext(i ->System.out.println(i.toString()+" emitted on "+Thread.currentThread().getId()))
    .flatMap(item -> Observable.just(item)
                         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()))    // make every item change to a new thread
    .subscribe(i -> {
        System.out.println(i.toString()+" received on "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
    });
```

Comment: It still running on the same thread. Maybe it's behavior of PublishProcessor?

`2 emitted on 1
3 emitted on 1
4 emitted on 1
5 emitted on 1
6 emitted on 1
3 received on 14
2 received on 14
4 received on 14
5 received on 14
6 received on 14`

Comment: The solution is to let it sleep in map block right after .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()
i.e
`.flatMap(item -> Flowable.just(item)`
                        `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())`
                        `.map(i -> {`
                            `System.out.println(i.toString()+" received on` `"+Thread.currentThread().getId());`
                            `Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);`
                            `return i;`
                        `}))`